# Send email in asynchronous method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asynchronous

I want to send email using smtp clinet. This operation should be executed in other thread in order to Redirect to Index page. So far I have written the following code.

```
private async Task<int> SendEmail(System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient smtp, System.Net.Mail.MailMessage m)
{
    smtp.Send(m);
    return 0;
}
```

This method is called in other async Task method in that way.

```
await SendEmail(smtp, m);
```

Is this proposition correct?

Comment: A method marked with `async` should also execute an `async` action using `await`. If that is not the case then you should not use `async` and if it also does not return a `Task`/`Task<T>` then remove that as well and just have it return an int. Finally if it *is* an async method just return `Task` if the return type is `void`.

Comment: it's very hard to say what is "correct" without knowing what you want to do and why. there is nothing in this code that starts a thread though, and the `Send` method is not asynchronous so I'm not sure what you think you're doing right now.

Comment: There is nothing about `async`/`await` that creates threads. Unless you `await` something that creates a thread then no new threads are created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the implementation of SendEmail to:

```
private async Task<int> SendEmail(System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient smtp, 
System.Net.Mail.MailMessage m)
{
    await smtp.SendAsync(m).ConfigureAwait(false);
    return 0;
}
```

Also see the following url:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx

**Async all the way**
Don’t mix blocking and async code.

**Configure context**
Use ConfigureAwait(false) when you can.